# combine multiple dataframe to a single one

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have 6 dataframes with same column names.
The column names are:
`"session_id", "player_id", "gersey_color","timestamp"`

data in each frame looks like:

| session_id | player_id | gersey_color | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123xyz | yellow | 9 | 1347.85 |

I want to combine these dataframe in single dataframe where the format would be like:

| session_id | player_info | df1 | df2 | df3 | df4 | df5 | df6 | total_occurance | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123xyz | yellow9 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 1347.85 |
|  | green2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 |  |
|  | blue5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 |  |
| 523pqr | yellow1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 747.45 |
|  | white2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 1 |  |
| 205abd | green1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 57.61 |
| 111mnz | yellow10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1821.21 |
|  | black2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 |  |

Here I am using timestamp as unique identifier and want to get the frequency of each time stamp happening across all the dataframe but categorised with `session_id` and `player_id and gersey_color` combined.

my current code can get all the information but can not format like the way I want:

```
    for i, combo_row in combo_df.iterrows():
       value_in_combo = combo_row['timestamp']
       count = 0

       player_info = []
       session_id = []
       for id, df_path in enumerate(df_list):
           rule_df = pd.read_excel(df_path)
           sub_counter = 0
           for idx, entry in rule_df.iterrows():
               idr = list(rule_df.columns).index('timestamp')
               value = entry[idr]
               s_id = entry[list(rule_df.columns).index('session.id')]
               player_team = entry[list(rule_df.columns).index('gersey_color')]
               player_num = entry[list(rule_df.columns).index('player_id')]
               if value == value_in_combo:
                   sub_counter+=1
                   session_id.append(s_id)
                   player_info.append(str(player_team)+str(player_num))
           combo_df.at[i, f'df{id+1}'] = ','.join(list(set(player_info)))
           combo_df.at[i, 'session_id'] =','.join(list(set(session_id)))
           count += sub_counter
       combo_df.at[i, 'occurrence_across_rules'] = count
```

Here `combo_df` is the df I predefined to populate all the data.

current `combo_df` looks like:

| session_id | player_info | df1 | df2 | df3 | df4 | df5 | df6 | timestamp | total_occurance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123xyz | yellow1 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 623.15 | 1 |
| 423pqz | green1,yellow5 |  | yellow55 |  | green1,yellow5 |  |  | 1347.85 | 5 |

. . . . . .
But as I said my code does not generate the format I want.
Can anyone suggest how to do it ?

Edit:
I solved the problem using:
`combo_df.set_index(['session_id', 'player_team', 'player_num'], inplace=True)`

Comment: If they all have the same structure, you can use `pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3])`.

Comment: Hi,
No, please read the problem again. I am filtering some data using timestamp and then want to combine in a particular format.

Comment: I think you need `DataFrame.merge`, but it's hard to say since you only provide one out of the three dataframes

Comment: @PaulH 
All the dateframes `df1,df2 ...df6` have same structure with similar or unique data. So, I thought putting so many tables in the post would only make it large.

Comment: If you can live with the `total_occurence` column only, and not each `df1`, `df2`, etc columns in your final data frame, you can add a counter columns filled with 1's to `df1`, `df2`, ..., `df6` and then use `concat(...).groupby(...).sum()` and the `total_occurences` will be right. Now your question is not properly defined as to what do you want to do with different entries for `timestamp`, but you could also handle that with a possibly different apply function and then `contact().groupby().apply(your_func)`.

Comment: Also as a general rule avoid iterating through your data frame. It is extremely slow and often with a bit of fiddling around with your input data you could stick to a purely "pandonic" way to achieve what you want...